# hadoop logging facility?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-zookeeper

If I am to use zookeeper as a work queue and connect to it individual consumers/workers.  What would you recommend as a good distributed setup for logging these workers' activities?

Assume the following:

1) At anytime we could be down to 1 single computer housing the hadoop cluster.  The system will autoscale up and down as needed but has alot of down time where only 1 single computer is needed.

2) I just need the ability to access all of the workers logs without accessing the individual machine that worker is located at.  Bare in mind, that by the time I get to read one of these logs that machine might very well be terminated and long gone.

3) We'll need easy access to the logs i.e being able to cat/grep and tail or alternatively in a more SQLish manner - we'll need real time ability to both query as well as monitor output for short periods of time in real time.  (i.e tail -f /var/log/mylog.1)

I appreciate your expert ideas here!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using Flume, chukwa or scribe - ensure that your flume etc process has access to the log files that you are trying to aggregate onto a centralized server.

flume reference:
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/Cookbook/

chukwa:
http://incubator.apache.org/chukwa/docs/r0.4.0/admin.html

scribe:
https://github.com/facebook/scribe/wiki/_pages

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) log collector just released its WebHDFS plugin, which allows the users to instantly stream data into HDFS. It's really easy to install with ease of management.

[image]

- [Fluentd + Hadoop: Instant Big Data Collection](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/http-to-hdfs)

Of course you can import data directly from your applications. Here's a Java example to post logs against Fluentd. Fluentd's Java library is clever enough to buffer locally when Fluentd daemon is down. This lessens the possibility of the data loss.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Java Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/java)

High availability configuration is also available, which basically enables you to have centralized log aggregation system.

- [Fluentd: High Availability Configuration](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/high-availability)